# Overlap divs within a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This might be quite easy but I'm having problems getting this to work the way I need.

I'm using bootstrap and below is my css and div structure. I'm having 3 divs hidden and 3 buttons to make them visible. My problem is how do I make the divs be in the same level? At the moment the 3 divs are one below the other.

For Better understanding I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lf9spha/).

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 wrapper">
     <div class="groupHolder">
          <div id="xx" class="overlapDiv" Style="background-color:#F00;">Fruits</div> // need these overlaping
          <div id="yy" class="overlapDiv" Style="background-color:#888;">Flowers</div> // need these overlaping
          <div id="zz" class="overlapDiv" Style="background-color:#f60;">Veggies</div> // need these overlaping
     </div>
    <div class="buttonHolder">
        <button type="button" id="aa" class="standardBtn">Btn 1</button>
        <button type="button" id="bb" class="standardBtn">Btn 2</button>
        <button type="button" id="cc" class="standardBtn">Btn 3</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, you want the colored labels in your fiddle to all appear in the same place?

Comment: @droo46: thanks. yes, that's what I want.

Comment: You could try absolute position, along with z-index.

Comment: I think this example will help you do just that: http://jsfiddle.net/ha6qp7w4/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `visibility` property just hide/show the element keeping the space of this element. If you want to remove the space of the element when it is invisible, you should use `display` property with block/none value.

like that :
https://jsfiddle.net/6Lf9spha/3/

Comment: @Bekki Depends on the content, but most common external content could be images - depends on the browser, but usually will load immediately even if set to `display: none` otherwise will load when you set it to `display: block`. Iframes - loads content independent from display property. Flash - depends on the flash.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`.overlapDiv {display: inline-block;}`

Z-index could work aswell

Comment: thanks. But no good. I want the 3 divs to be same as in my fiddle (100% width and center aligned) as Yoann Augen's answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need, one of the possibilities is to not only make them invisible but hide them completely by changing `visibility: hidden` to `display: none`

```
$("#aa").click(function(){
   $('.overlapDiv').css('display', 'none');
   $('#xx').css('display', 'block');
});


overlapDiv{
    display: block;
}
/* Make all elements except the first one hidden by default */
.overlapDiv:nth-child(n+2){
    display: none;
}
```

Visibility affects if the element is visible, but does not change its playe in layout. ex. Element with `visibility: hidden` will still take space on the page, `display: none` will not.

```js
$("#aa").click(function(){
   $('.overlapDiv').css('display', 'none');
   $('#xx').css('display', 'block');
});

$("#bb").click(function(){
   $('.overlapDiv').css('display', 'none');
   $('#yy').css('display', 'block');
});

$("#cc").click(function(){
   $('.overlapDiv').css('display', 'none');
   $('#zz').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
 margin-top: 25px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.buttonHolder{
 position: relative;
}
.groupHolder{
   overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.overlapDiv{
 display: block;
}
.overlapDiv:nth-child(n+2){
    display: none;  
}
.standardBtn{
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 12px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 wrapper">
     <div class="groupHolder">
          <div id="xx" class="overlapDiv" Style="background-color:#F00;">Fruits</div>
          <div id="yy" class="overlapDiv" Style="background-color:#888;">Flowers</div>
          <div id="zz" class="overlapDiv" Style="background-color:#f60;">Veggies</div>
     </div>
    <div class="buttonHolder">
        <button type="button" id="aa" class="standardBtn">Btn 1</button>
        <button type="button" id="bb" class="standardBtn">Btn 2</button>
        <button type="button" id="cc" class="standardBtn">Btn 3</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```